# Read JSON file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an online JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200
    },
    "response": {
        "item": {
            "isLive": false,
            "eventStartTime": "2020-03-26T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
}
```

I need a JavaScript function that parses this data to get "isLive". This JSON file is online and only accessible via direct url.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Look into "ajax" and the built-in `JSON.parse()` command. As @palaѕн you'll need to do some research. Also a code attempt will help this question not end up being downvoted.

Comment: Sounds good, Thank you @palash and GetSet for your help! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to access: `data.response.item.isLive` If you are requesting the file directly, make sure to send an appropriate response type header of `application/json` so that you DO NOT need to parse.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not using jQuery, as the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API is available.

```js
let isLive = false;

fetch('ajax/test.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    isLive = json.response.item.isLive
  });
```

---

### Live example

Here is a live example using sample JSON.

```js
let isTaskCompleted = false;

const showStatus = () => {
  let el = document.querySelector('#completed');
  el.textContent = isTaskCompleted ? 'YES' : 'NO';
  el.setAttribute('data-completed', isTaskCompleted);
};

// Change the id from `4` to `1` to get a result of `false`.
// See: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    isTaskCompleted = json.completed;
    showStatus();
  });
```

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.status[data-completed="false"] {
  color: #A00;
}
.status[data-completed="true"] {
  color: #0A0;
}
```

```html
<label>Completed:</label> <span id="completed" class="status"></span>
```

Comment: what is the reason to use second `.then` method? Why can't we do the same in first one?

Comment: @Leonid [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: OK) Thanks. So there is no sure reason to do it....

Comment: @Leonid Well, you can handle bad data in the first promise and manually reject the chain, if you need to. See: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-use-the-fetch-method-to-make-multiple-api-calls-with-vanilla-javascript/ It's the convention that everyone uses.

Comment: @Polywhirl would this work the same way for an online JSON file for example located at "https://www.jamesriver.tv/api/v1/events/current"?

Comment: @KolemanParsley Yep, just change the URL and the result to be `json.response.item.isLive`

Comment: @Polywhirl, i am confused on what that response is supposed to mean, to clarify, i am replacing 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4' with my URL and then replacing showStatus to json.response.item.isLive ?

Comment: @Polywhirl Is that all i do?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```js
let isLive;

$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    isLive = data.response.item.isLive;
});
```

Using `fetch()`:

```
let response = await fetch("ajax/test.json");

if (response.ok) {
  let isLive = await response.json().response.item.isLive;
} else {
  alert("Error HTTP: " + response.status);
}
```

Comment: The response is not nested in meta.... OP's format is bad, I will fix it. Also, you can do this with `fetch` instead.

Comment: Your latest edit is invalid. You can't return anything from an async request. `isLive` will hold the promise, not the value in `data.response.item.isLive`. I've rolled it back for you as the previous answer was correct

Comment: OK, sure,  you are RIGHT!

Answer (score -1):

you can use Ajax for read this file

```js
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  //data is JSON file ccontent
  JsonDataFile=JSON.parse(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse()` when using `getJSON()` - jQuery automatically does it for you. Parsing twice will cause an error.

Comment: thanks for this comment